# Input Date Value Not Updating With Moment

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

I've searched every possible solution I can find, but nothing found for react... only C# and jQuery.

**The Problem:**

I'm trying to get the dates to update the values both in the html input element and in the useState hook upon user selecting a date. I can see neither the state nor input is being updated.

Once the values are able to instantiate, I can finally do my comparisons to throw up an error if the before and after dates are invalid.

**The Code:**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import moment from "moment";

export default function App() {
  const [dateRange, setDateRange] = useState({
    startDate: new Date("0001-01-01T00:00:00"),
    endDate: new Date("0001-01-01T00:00:00")
  });
  const [startDateValidCheck, setStartDateValidCheck] = useState({
    isInvalid: false
  });
  const [endDateValidCheck, setEndDateValidCheck] = useState({
    isInvalid: false
  });
  const [rangeDateValidCheck, setRangeDateValidCheck] = useState({
    isInvalid: false,
    msg: ""
  });
  const [isDatesReady, setIsDatesReady] = useState(false);
  const handleDateValueChange = (ev, valueType = "") => {
    if (valueType === "startDate") {
      setDateRange({ ...dateRange, [ev.target.name]: ev.target.valueAsDate });
    } else if (valueType === "endDate") {
      setDateRange({ ...dateRange, [ev.target.name]: ev.target.valueAsDate });
    }
  };
  const handleSubmit = (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault();

    // Reset Validation State
    setStartDateValidCheck({ isInvalid: false });
    setEndDateValidCheck({ isInvalid: false });
    setRangeDateValidCheck({ isInvalid: false, msg: "" });

    // Validation checking
    let isInvalid = false;
    console.log(
      "dateRange.startDate",
      moment(dateRange.startDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
    );
    console.log("dateRange.endDate", dateRange.endDate);
    if (
      !dateRange.startDate.toString().includes("Mon Jan 01 0001 00:00:00") &&
      !dateRange.endDate.toString().includes("Mon Jan 01 0001 00:00:00") &&
      dateRange.startDate.value > dateRange.endDate.value
    ) {
      isInvalid = true;
      setStartDateValidCheck({ isInvalid: true, msg: "" });
      setEndDateValidCheck({ isInvalid: true, msg: "" });
      setRangeDateValidCheck({
        isInvalid: true,
        msg: "Start Date must be before End Date"
      });
    }
    if (!isInvalid) {
      setIsDatesReady(true);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <form className="form-dates" onSubmit={(ev) => handleSubmit(ev)}>
        <div>
          <div className="div-display-flex">
            <div className="div-date">
              <label htmlFor="startDate">Start</label>
              <input
                type="date"
                name="startDate"
                onChange={(ev) => handleDateValueChange(ev)}
                value={moment(dateRange.startDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD")}
                className={
                  startDateValidCheck.isInvalid
                    ? "input-calander-error"
                    : "input-calander"
                }
              />
            </div>
            <div className="div-date">
              <label htmlFor="endDate">End</label>
              <input
                type="date"
                name="endDate"
                onChange={(ev) => handleDateValueChange(ev)}
                value={moment(dateRange.endDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD")}
                className={
                  endDateValidCheck.isInvalid
                    ? "input-calander-error"
                    : "input-calander"
                }
              />
            </div>
            {rangeDateValidCheck.isInvalid && (
              <p className="p-error-compare-dates">{rangeDateValidCheck.msg}</p>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" className="btn-submit">
          Show&nbsp;Dates
        </button>
      </form>
      {isDatesReady && (
        <p>
          Start&nbsp;Date:&nbsp;
          {moment(dateRange.startDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD")}
        </p>
      )}
      {isDatesReady && (
        <p>
          End&nbsp;Date:&nbsp;{moment(dateRange.startDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD")}
        </p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have the live version here: https://codesandbox.io/s/dates-gxvg3

Anyone have any idea what I'm missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your onchange handler expects the type of input, as well as event object:

```
const handleDateValueChange = (ev, valueType = "") => {
    if (valueType === "startDate") {
      setDateRange({ ...dateRange, [ev.target.name]: ev.target.valueAsDate });
    } else if (valueType === "endDate") {
      setDateRange({ ...dateRange, [ev.target.name]: ev.target.valueAsDate });
    }
  };
```

But you're not passing the input type in here :

```
<input onChange={(ev) => handleDateValueChange(ev)} ... >
```

So change it to :

```
<input onChange={(ev) => handleDateValueChange(ev, "startDate")} ... >
```

And same for endDate.

Update: Also you can call `handleSubmit();` function on `handleDateValueChange`, to see the changes as soon as user selects a data.

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dates-oirzk?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Great catch! Thank you so much. I'll leave this question up as an example since I didn't see any for reactjs/hooks.

Comment: @FiddleFreak no problem, but didn't understand what you mean about : `since I didn't see any for reactjs/hooks` ? didn't it solve it completely?

Comment: @FiddleFreak updated the code to show the changed values as soon as user select, and updated the answer also. (if it was what you want.)

Comment: `useState` is using react hooks and this code is written in reactjs. And yeah I just fixed the prod code so everything is working great now :)